# Can 2 functions be defined in one WebJob?

Tags: c#, azure-webjobs, timer-trigger

In one WebJob I launched 2 functions:one is a ServiceBusTrigger one and the other is a TimerTrigger one. 
Can the 2 function both work? Seems the ServiceBusTrigger works and TimerTrigger one does not. 
The TimerTrigger one is defined as

```
public void CheckExpiration([TimerTrigger("0 */5 * * * *")]TimerInfo myTimer)
```

So it should run every 5 minutes? I log the trace when the function get called yet I do not find the expected trace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please make sure you have added `config.UseTimers()` in your program.cs. If you want to use [TimeTrigger](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk-extensions/wiki/TimerTrigger) in webjobs, you need to add this code. The reference of this code is in **Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions** nuget package. I have tested two Functions in webjob. Every thing works fine. The TimeTrigger is triggered every 1 minute automatically.

[image]

Comment: If my answer is helpful, please don't forget to mark it as answer to let other community members find. Thinks.

Comment: Thanks for check and sorry for delayed response. It really works per you suggestion. I did not call config.UseTimers() at that time.

Comment: PS: how to mark your comment as answer? I did not find the relevant button on the page...

Comment: The comment can not be marked. But you could vote up the answer or comment. Just click the up button at the left corner.

Comment: I click "accept" fork sign on the answer. Also click  the up button yet it says my reputation is less than 15 so will not be displayed...

Comment: Yes. You need to get more scores to get new permissions. You are still a new member in stackoverflow.

Comment: Thanks for comments. I have a confusing issue on  trap of ' azure api app'. Can I get some support on development if I call "400-089-0365 or +86-10-8456-3652" tomorrow?

Comment: You could contact Microsoft Azure from this [article](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/support/options/)(email, phone,post thread or any other).